# pytest-xdist generate random & uniqe ports for each test

Tags: python, pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist

I'm using pytest-xdist plugin to run some test using the `@pytest.mark.parametrize` to run the same test with different parameters.

As part of these tests, I need to open/close web servers and the ports are generated at collection time.

xdist does the test collection on the slave and they are not synchronised, so how can I guarantee uniqueness for the port generation.

I can use the same port for each slave but I don't know how to archive this.

Comment: what do you mean open/close web servers? a web server is not something you open or close its something you connect to and disconnect from

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: what do you man by "archive this"?

Comment: bind to port 0 and the OS will give you a random free port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured that I did not give enough information regarding my issue.

What I did was to create one parameterized test using `@pytest.mark.parametrize` and before the test, I collect the list of parameters, the collection query a web server and receive a list of "jobs" to process.

Each test contains information on a port that he needs to bind to, do some work and exit because the tests are running in parallel I need to make sure that the ports will be different.

Eventually, I make sure that the job ids will be in the rand on 1024-65000 and used that for the port.